# How to find the max object as per some custom criterion?

Tags: python

I can do `max(s)` to find the max of a sequence. But suppose I want to compute max according to my own function, something like:

```
currmax = 0
def mymax(s):
  for i in s :
    #assume arity() attribute is present
    currmax = i.arity() if i.arity() > currmax else currmax
```

Is there a clean pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 41):

```
max(s, key=operator.methodcaller('arity'))
```

or

```
max(s, key=lambda x: x.arity())
```

Comment: This is what the title sounds like it is asking for, but the code posted finds the value of `i.arity()`, not the value of `i`

Comment: @JohnLaRooy-AKAgnibbler: I think you said that backwards, this answer returns the element (`i`) that had the the maximum value of calling the `arity()` method on it, not what that value was, which is not what `currmax` is in the OP's code (and is probably what they are trying to determine) — so I'd have to agree that it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 12):

For instance,

```
max (i.arity() for i in s)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can still use the `max` function:

```
max_arity = max(s, key=lambda i: i.arity())
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Good answer.  However, anytime you use a lambda, think about if you have to.  Its almost always more pythonic to use a generator expression like doublep does above.

Answer (score 2):

I think the generator expression of doublep is better, but we seldom get to use methodcaller, so...

```
from operator import methodcaller
max(map(methodcaller('arity'), s))
```