# How to get values of class method after calculating min of other class value

Tags: python, oop, min

I have a "Node" class which takes as arguments x and y. The class methods calculate different values. I have multiple instances of this class called "nodes". What I want is to find the node with the lowest "fcost" and get the x and y coordinates of that node.

I have no idea how to solve this problem so it would be much appreciated if you could help me.

```py
class Node():

    # Node class

    def __init__(self, y, x):
        self.y = y
        self.x = x        

    def gcost(self):
        return self.x + self.y

    def hcost(self):
        return self.x * self.y

    def fcost(self):
        return self.gcost() + self.hcost()  # method that indicates 
                                            # which node to choose 

node1 = Node(5,5)
node2 = Node(2,2)

nodes = [node1, node2]  # I actually don't know if I should create a 
                        # list of nodes so please tell me if I should 
                        # not

### CODE TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM ###
```

In this case the lowest fcost between node1 and node2 is node2's fcost so I expect the output to be:
`(2,2)` or `[2,2]`
Either a list or a tuple, either way is fine.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you know about the `min` function? Do you know that you can pass a `key` to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding max in python as per some custom criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931985/finding-max-in-python-as-per-some-custom-criterion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `min()` function. You can use it in different ways, but in this scenario, I think that the simplest solution would be to use a lambda function - which is a shorter way to write and define functions in python.
You can read more about the `min()` function [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#min), and more about lambda functions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

**Anyway, this piece of code should work just fine:**

```
class Node():

# Node class

def __init__(self, y, x):
    self.y = y
    self.x = x        

def gcost(self):
    return self.x + self.y

def hcost(self):
    return self.x * self.y

def fcost(self):
    return self.gcost() + self.hcost()

node1 = Node(5,5)
node2 = Node(2,2)
nodes = [node1, node2]

needed_node = min(nodes, key=lambda x:x.fcost())
needed_list = [needed_node.x, needed_node.y]  # in case you want the result as a list
needed_tuple = (needed_node.x, needed_node.y)  # in case you want the result as a tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `min(list, key=...)`.

```
min_node = min(nodes, key=lambda n:n.fcost())

print(min_node, min_node.fcost(), min_node.x, min_node.y)
```

`key` has to be name of function.

`min` will use it to get value which it will compare to find minimal one.