# How to find the max value in a string of poker ranks

Tags: python, python-3.x

The poker ranks go in order like this. '23456789TJQKA' where T is ten and then jack queen king and Ace with Ace being the highest card. A string is inputed and is always inputed as a 5 character string.

If the user inputs lets say string = '43TKQ' How can I find the highest card in this string without any advanced methods only if statements, while and for loops. I tried max(string) but it returns ten and not King

```
hand = '28TKQ'

print(max(hand)) #This outputs T (it should output K)
```

'768TA' should print A

'2TJ67' should print J

Comment: So how do you do this on paper?  How do you use the reference string to figure out that `J` is more then `T` in this case?  Analyze the problem and implement your human logic as Python code.  *Then* you'll have an attempt to post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding max in python as per some custom criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931985/finding-max-in-python-as-per-some-custom-criterion)

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify to Order logic witch is `23456789TJQKA`:

```
order = '23456789TJQKA'

print(max('28TKQ', key=lambda e: order.index(e)))   # K
print(max('A43TKQ', key=lambda e: order.index(e)))  # A
```

Another pythonic code:

```
cards = '23456789TJQKA'

print(max('28TKQ', key=cards.index))   # K
print(max('A43TKQ', key=cards.index))    # A
```

**EDITS**

To answer your comment:

when you search for `max` in list element you will compare items, by default `str` are compared by `Unicode code point`, so when you compare element of list `28TKQ` `'T'` have the biggest value `84`,   `ord('T') > ord('K')`  and this why `max` returned `T` not `K`, but you don't what this logic of compression you need to tell `max` that you want a different logic in comparing.

this why we use the `key` parameter that we pass a method and the item are ordered based on the return value of that method.

**Edits:**

To clear thing for you more

```
# 2 priority is 0, ....., A priority is 12
card_priority = '23456789TJQKA'


def get_card_priority(card):
    """ return the priority of card, it's index in card_priority list"""
    return card_priority.index(card)


# compare get_card_priority('2') = 0, get_card_priority('8') = 6,get_card_priority('T')=8.......get_card_priority('Q') = 10
# The element with the highest value is returned witch is 'K' = 11
print(max('28TKQ', key=get_card_priority))  # K because get_card_priority('K') return the biggest value
```

Comment: What is key=lambda e and order.index(e))) do?

Comment: So key=lambda e : order.index(e) changes the logic of the order by setting the order in the defined string order = '23456789TJQKA' ?

Comment: I am just confused because I have not learned lambda or key in class yet and I am having trouble understanding it

Comment: max accept a method `key` then call this method on each element and compare the returned value. ` lambda`  is a way to create an anonymous function it's equavalent to  `def some_name(e): return order.index(e)`

Comment: Just google it, key argument like in , `sort, filter, max, min, sum....` it's not that hard after few simple example you will understand what they do. one thing if you don't know it you can pass a method as an argument to a call of another method. like here we passed a function that we created using lambda expression and max use that function on each element hope this clears a little bit thing.

Comment: Ok I think I got it but just to clarify. So that line returns the maximum value of '28TKA' with respect to whatever is returned by key for each element in order ?

Comment: yes, let say that lambda create a function is name is index_of,  it will compare the return value from this call,  `index_of('2'), index_of('8'), index_of('T') .... index_of('A')` this function return the index of card in the order list. and `'A'` is the in the last index to it's returned value is the biggest one so max return it. if this clarify thing for you consider to accept the answer, and good luck in your carrier

Comment: Much appreciated I totally understand now